# Footer top position is smaller on home page, but normal size on others

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to build a web page. 
For some reason on my home page the value of `$('.footer').position().top` is smaller than the other pages. 
For `#home` it returns 44 but `$(document).height() = 3066`
On `#learningCenter` it returns 866 and `$(document).height() = 1011`.

I'm not able to provide all the content for privacy reasons but does any have an idea of what's going on?

An example of some of my code.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#learningCenter">Learning Center</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active container-fluid"></div> 
        <div id="learningCenter" class="tab-pane fade in"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer navbar-static-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <img id="footer-logo" src="media/logo.PNG"/>
            <p><span id="semiBold">Page &copy;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <p>Terms of Use &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Privacy &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Report Bug&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my `#home`div/tab-pane had `position: absolute`, changing to `position: relative` fixed it!